# JavaScript - 3 Boolean operators in If statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, comparison

Okay, so there are three boolean values. Only one boolean value can be true at a time. If one of the boolean values is already true, it should stay true if the condition hits it, it should not revert back to false. Note that activeCrate1 should be **true** by default.

When the condition hits activeCrate2, it is true and all other boolean cases are false.

When the condition hits activeCrate3, it is true and all other boolean cases are false.

But how do I hit activeCrate1, and return it again to true, and all other boolean values should be false?

**And for example**, if the condition hits activeCrate1 which is already **True**, it should stay true and nothing should change. How can I make it work that way?

Two questions in total, but need to be implemented in the same code.

My code looks like this:

```
activeCrate1: true,
activeCrate2: false,
activeCrate3: false

if (state.activeCrate2 === false ) {
    state.activeCrate2 = true
    state.activeCrate1 = false;
    state.activeCrate3 = false;
  } else if (state.activeCrate3 == false){
    state.activeCrate3 = true;
    state.activeCrate1 = false;
    state.activeCrate2 = false;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You state the exact steps of how it should behave, and then ask how to do it. You literally say it: "if the condition hits... it should stay true". So then write an `if` statement and don't change it?

Comment: please add some use cases and separate the question into parts.

Comment: All you need is  one else{
activeCrate1: true,
activeCrate2: false,
activeCrate3: false,
} after else if. I guess this is what you wanted

Comment: My code works for activeCrate2 and activeCrate3, but the case for activeCase1 would not work properly, that is why I didn't include it in the code.

Comment: Only one boolean value can be True, and when it happends, all other values should be False. If the activeCrate1 is already True, it should remain True if the same condition hits it twice in a row, or an infinite number of times, so it is not reverting True-False value inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have only one active item among a list and let it change over time.

I think it would be easier to avoid controlling each case with ifs because it will be easy to leave bugs each time you want to add an activeCrate.

Let me rephrase what I think you said:

1. I want an initial list of default booleans with the first item set to true.
2. I want to update the list.
3. If the selected item is the same as before I change nothing.
4. Find the previous true value and set it to false.
5. Set the new item to true.

Here is the es5 javascript equivalent of what I wrote:

```
var activeCrates = [true, false, false];

function setActiveCrate(index) {
    // Short circuit code when the same crate is active
    if (activeCrates[index] === true) {
        return;
    }

    // Find previous active crate in order to set it to false
    var previousActiveCrate = activeCrates.indexOf(true);
    activeCrates[previousActiveCrate] = false;

    // Set current active crate to true
    activeCrates[index] = true;
}
```

Also note that I mutate the activeCrates array.